# Chart control stop dynamically updated after few minutes

Tags: c#, charts

I have application with real time Chart control that received date and display this on my control:

This is my control:

```
MyObject obj...

Series series = new Series();
series.Color = Color.Blue;
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
series.BorderWidth = 2;
chart1.Series.Add(series);
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number
```

;

Timer tick:

```
private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        series.Points.Add(wf.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001);
        chart1.ResetAutoValues();
}
```

My problem is that after few minutes the graph stop to update and stop moving forward and i don't know why.

Comment: In the debugger, can you see the points getting added to the series? Or does the timer stop ticking? Does it update fine until your points reach the axis maximum, and after that it doesn't update fine? You may need to add a call to `chart1.ResetAutoValues()` at the end of your `chartTimer_Tick` method, which would tell the chart to recalculate the min/max on both axes and account for the other points.

Comment: First at the end of chartTimer_i added a call to chart1.ResetAutoValues() and now i am test it again and i will update in a few minutes..., The timer is still ticking, what do you mean until your points reach the axis maximum ?

Comment: For instance, if your x-axis maximum is 100, and your timer adds points with x values increasing by 1....does it work for all points with x values less than 100, and stop working when it starts to add points with x values greater than 100?

Comment: the value that need to be added to my graph is also inside label so i can see that this value is fine, also look at this link, this is the strange behavior after a few minutes: http://s27.postimg.org/mk72uh32r/Untitled.jpg

Comment: BTW i didn't configure any x-axis maximum, what is the default ?

Comment: Now i can see that it still happen this behavior, what can i do ? see my chartTimer_Tick update

Answer (score 0):

After a while you will have too many `DataPoints` to display.

So best **remove** the old ones from the start:

```
private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    series.Points.Add(wf.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001);
    if (series.Points.Count > someLimit) series.Points.RemoveAt(0);
    chart1.ResetAutoValues();
}
```